# unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str' on pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting the error that += is not the operation used for int and string
the code is

```
while True:
    cards = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14']
    DC = random.choice(cards)
    PC += DC
    card = random.choice(cards)
    CC += DC
    again = input("again : ")
    if again == "no":
        print("Ok")
        if 21 < PC:
            print("YOU LOSS")
            break
        elif PC > CC:
            print("YOU WON")
            break
        else:
            print("YOU LOSS")
            break
    elif 21 < PC:
        print(nick, "LOSE")
        break
```

the problem is with PC += DC and CC += DC

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? And you haven't shown us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we don't have all information needed.

Comment: Well the error should be quite clear: You try to add a string to a number, which isn't allowed. What are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps `cards` should be a list of *integers*?

Answer (score 1):

Your cards variable is a list of strings, not integers. You can't add a string and an integer together in python. They are separate classes.

Edit: I'm assuming you are assigning PC and CC to 0
Edit 2: Don;t know what the "Nick" variable is assigned to. Shouldn't make a dif.

```
import random
PC= 0 # <--|  not sure if they are what you are assigning them 

while True:
    cards = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14']
    DC = random.choice(cards)
    PC += int(DC) # <-- Notice
    card = random.choice(cards)
    CC += int(DC)# <-- Notice
    again = input("again : ")
    if again == "no":
        print("Ok")
        if 21 < PC:
            print("YOU LOSS")
            break
        elif PC > CC:
            print("YOU WON")
            break
        else:
            print("YOU LOSS")
            break
    elif 21 < PC:
        print(nick, "LOSE")
        break
```

Here you are!

Results:

```
again : >? 23
again : >? 2
again : >? 54
LOSE
```